# OpenCV keeps installing on Python2 in Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv

How can I install opencv on python3 in rpi? I have python 3.8 installed and I also have changed default python to 3.8 . My rpi model is 3B
Thanks

Comment: you should explain *how* you install OpenCV and you should show the complete output of that action

Answer (score 1):

Try out `pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: I tried that as well but it automatically reboots rpi

Comment: does it **really** "automatically reboot"? does it say that? or does it just crash the pi and cause it to reboot?